# Update_attributes with a Date field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I ask the user to choose hos borthday from a date select :

```
<%= select_date Date.today, :prefix => :birthday %>
```

So in my action, i got a post like this :

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"_method"=>"put",
"authenticity_token"=>"k6uuDBVy2sM0YU7MtFIk7MsYpTQvQNnW5xuNRwn+OO0=",
"user"=>{"civility"=>"mr",
"password"=>"[FILTERED]",
"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
"current_password"=>"[FILTERED]",
"newsletter_register"=>"1"},
"birthday"=>{"year"=>"2011",
"month"=>"10",
"day"=>"25"},
"commit.x"=>"69",
"commit.y"=>"9"}
```

But when i use  :

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

The birthday field is not updated. Any idea?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the submitted parameters, the `birthday` field is not included in the `user` hash, but rather as a separate field.

You probably want something like this instead (if you give us the code for your current form, I can give a more specific answer):

```
<%= f.date_select :birthday %>
```